# MVVM RaisePropertyChanged throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light

My ViewModel runs fine the first time I open it, the 2nd time though something seems to be happening with my "loaded" eventToCommand. When I open it a 2nd time I get this exception on RaisePropertyChanged:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'UwpApp.ViewModel.QuizTeamViewModel' to type 'UwpApp.Model.Round'.'
```

Does this have anthing to do with the loaded command?

**ViewModel**

```
public QuizTeamViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            _navigationService = navigationService;

            MessengerInstance.Register<Quiz>(this, "SelectedQuiz", quiz => Quiz = quiz);

            SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<Round>(ChangeSelectedRound);
            ViewLoadedCommand = new RelayCommand(ViewLoaded);
            ClickRankingQuizTeamCommand = new RelayCommand(OnRankingQuizTeamClick);
        }

        private void ViewLoaded()
        {
            if (Quiz == null) return;
            Rounds = new ObservableCollection<Round>(Quiz.Rounds);
            RaisePropertyChanged("Rounds");

            FillQuizTeams();
        }

        private async void FillQuizTeams()
        {
            var quizTeamsToDisplay = new ObservableCollection<QuizTeamListViewModel>();
            foreach (var quizTeam in Quiz.QuizTeams)
            {
                var team = await ApiService<Team>.GetAsync($"{StaticUri.GetUri()}/teams/quizTeam/{quizTeam.Id}");
                quizTeam.Name = team.Name;
                quizTeamsToDisplay.Add(new QuizTeamListViewModel(quizTeam, this));
            }

            QuizTeams = quizTeamsToDisplay;
            RaisePropertyChanged("QuizTeams");
        }
```

**Xaml**

```
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ViewLoadedCommand}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: Try to debug the code first. You have the error message so probably you know the line where it occurs. The question is not specific enough to help you solve the problem. Try to narrow it.

Comment: I did debug the code and nothing came out, for some reason the RaisePropertyChanged just can’t seem to find the properties in the viewmodel in the view loaded function.

Comment: Do you mean when you trigger the ViewLoaded method a second time, the error occurs? In addition, I can't reproduce this issue, so can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: You might want to modify your exception settings so that the debugger stops whenever this exception is *raised* (not only when it is not cought).

Comment: I have no idea how to reproduce this issue, in ViewLoaded when I call RaisePropertyChanged() without parameters no exceptions seem to be thrown. Something really seems wrong with my properties when I load the ViewModel a second time. (RaisePropertyChanged without params doesn't update my Rounds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my combobox wasn't always sending a Round object to my command, due to this it was trying to cast the wrong object to Round.

What I did to fix it was change the Type in SelectionChangedCommand to object and check in the RelayCommand method if the object is a Round.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Please select this as the answer